# ¿dos botones de copiar?

Tags: javascript, java, web, script, botón

```
  Tengo dos botones de copiar, uno quiero que copie una cosa y el otro otra, ¿como hago para que no copien los dos lo mismo?
```

He probado hacer dos códigos iguales y cambiar el ID para que copie el otro pero sigue copiando el mismo.

Código javascript:

```
function myFunction() {

  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);


  document.execCommand("copy");

  alert("Servidor Copiado " + copyText.value);
} 

 function myFunction() {

  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput1");

  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);


  document.execCommand("copy");

  alert("Servidor Copiado " + copyText.value);
}
```

HTML:

```
<input class="btn-brown btn" type="text" value="mc.minecraft.com" readonly="readonly" id="myInput">
<button class="btn-brown btn" onclick="myFunction()">Copiar</button>
<input class="btn-brown btn" type="text" value="discord.minecraft.com" readonly="readonly" id="myInput1">
<button class="btn-brown btn" onclick="myFunction()">Copiar</button>
```

Comment: Buenas tardes @Vance Dyer me parece que el problema es que ambas funciones se llaman de la misma forma intenta nombrarlas distinto algo asi como `copyInputText()` y `copySecondInputText()` porque por lo demas tu codigo deberia de funcionar

Comment: Lo recomendable es no realizar varios métodos, realiza uno donde se defina lógica a realizar dependiendo de una variable @VanceDyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes modificar el nombre de una de las dos funciones Javascript *myFunction()*, y después cambiar también la llamada a esta nueva función en el onclick del tag button que desees.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 3):

Cuando programas es recomendable no realizar varias funciones o métodos que realicen tareas similares, por lo tanto puedes usar solo una función, la cual reciba un valor que determine el tipo de copiado realizara:

```
function myFunction(idCopiado) {
 ...
 ...
}
```

dentro puedes usar un `if` o un `switch` para implementar la lógica que realizará tu función, este es un ejemplo usando un `switch`.

```
function myFunction(idCopiado) {
  switch(idCopiado){
      case 1:
        ...
        ...
        alert("Tipo de copiado A ");     
       break;
      case 2:
        ...
        ...
        alert("Tipo de copiado B ");     
      break; 
      default:
        alert("Opción no definida.");            
      break;
  }

}
```

---

Este sería el ejemplo de acuerdo a tu código.

```js
function myFunction(idCopiado) {

  switch(idCopiado){
      case 1:
        var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        alert("1) Servidor Copiado " + copyText.value);     
       break;
      case 2:
        var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput1");
        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        alert("2) Servidor Copiado " + copyText.value);            
      break; 
      default:
        alert("Opción no definida.");            
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
 <input class="btn-brown btn" type="text" value="mc.minecraft.com" readonly="readonly" id="myInput">
 <button class="btn-brown btn" onclick="myFunction(1)">Copiar</button>
 <input class="btn-brown btn" type="text" value="discord.minecraft.com" readonly="readonly" id="myInput1">
 <button class="btn-brown btn" onclick="myFunction(2)">Copiar</button>
```